# Score in leaderboard isn't updated

Tags: android, python, kivy, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have build a game with python-kivy framework and integrated google play gam services. I can list scores and achievements. In my first attempt, I am able to be listed in the leaderboard. But future updates doesn't make affect. Always first score is listed. It doesn't dump any error or warning in logcat.

I have followed same procedure in this link. https://github.com/tito/2048

I have used all libraries under libs directory. I have also directly copied `gs_android.py` file and call functions in this file from my `App` object.

I am testing my game in debug mode at this moment. May it be a behavour of debug mode of game services?

Any help and recommendation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long period of research process, I have decided to delete current leaderboard and initialized new one. This has solved my problem.

I have informed google play services team about this problem(before solution) but they just ignored it by saying that it was the first time when someone came with this problem.

Just keep in mind that everyone is human, so may be error-prone.